# Does there always exist atlest two sequences that converge to the same limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

In a bounded set of real numbers,   Does there always exist atlest two sequences that converge to the same limit?

From Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, there is always one sequence exist that converge,

Can I somehow make a twin sequence if i already have one?

Comment: The sentence, "Can I somehow make a twin sequence if i already have one?" can be made more precise by replacing "twin" with "different".

Answer (score 3):

No. Take the singleton set $S = \{a\}$ for some $a \in \mathbb R$. Then the only sequence in $S$ converging to $a$ is the constant sequence.

On the other hand, if $S$ has at least two elements, this is easily possible. If you have any sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converging to $a \in S$, you can change the pick another element $a_1' \neq a_1$, and the sequence
$$a_1', a_2, a_3, a_4, \dotsc$$
also converges to $a$.

Comment: What about infinte set?

Comment: @multipleof3 Infinite sets have at least two elements, so the second paragraph applies.